# useMeta not updating title in Nuxt Composition API

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, meta-tags

Here is my code inside the Component Script : Title tag doesn't show up when I inspect

```
import {  useMeta } from "@nuxtjs/composition-api";

export default {
 components: {  }, 

head: {},

setup() {

useMeta({
        title: 'My title',
        meta: [
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content: 'My description',
            },
        ],
    })


const screenType = ref("desktop");
var deviceType = ""
// const screenType = ref("mobile")
// const screenType = ref("landscape")

if (process.browser) {
    window.onNuxtReady(() => {
        if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
        screenType.value = "mobile";
        } else {
        screenType.value = "desktop";
        }

       
        

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/mobile/i)) {
            deviceType =  "mobile";
        } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|Android|Touch/i)) {
            deviceType = "tablet";
        } else {
            deviceType = "desktop";
        }


    })
 }



} }
```

There is no head object in my `nuxt.config.js`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use it like this in your setup function in your Page component with `defineComponent` :

```js
export default defineComponent({
    head: {}, // Needed in nuxt 2
    setup() {
        const { title, meta } = useMeta()
        title.value = 'My title'
        meta.value = [
            {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content:
                'My description',
            },
        ]
    },
  })
```

https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/packages/useMeta

Comment: I tried this, doesn't seem to work. I'm able to log the title and meta values but it's not updating in the browser. I'm running this on dev, will it work only with build?

Comment: Make sure you use this only on a Page component

Comment: This is my file structure > pages > widgets > _id.vue. My code is in _id.vue

Comment: You also need to use defineComponent

Answer (score 3):

You should use defineComponent imported from "@nuxtjs/composition-api". Do not use defineComponent imported from "@vue/composition-api".

Comment: Read [answer]: Could you explain _why_ the former should be used and not the latter?

Comment: The former should be used uniformly, because if the two are used together, it will cause invalidation caused by incompatibility.